# Editing UEFN maps with friends without using Teams?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

Creating maps with friends in UEFN, or Fortnite Creative 2.0, has always been a bit of a mess. It took a bit of effort and alot of luck to get friends into a work-in-progress map where they could assist in creating it, but eventually we would manage to all get in without any errors and be able to edit the maps together. We took a break from UEFN for a while and now that we're trying to get back to working on the map we had been working on before we can't seem to get the whole squad into Creative 2.0 together. If friends try to join while the creator is on the map or the Editor is connected they get a Matchmaking Error. If we all join into the Hub and then try to connect the Editor it wants to start a new session, returning everybody to the lobby.

I've tried looking up a guide for this in case changes were made to how it works, but all I've found is a tutorial for creating Teams. Teams requires some sort of verification that needs a credit card and to spend a tiny amount of money though and one of the friends that was doing roughly half the work on the map doesn't have a credit card so he can't go through Teams. So Teams isn't an option.

How do we get friends into Fortnite Creative 2.0 with edit permissions without using Teams in January 2024?